# How can I save an image after manipulating it?

Tags: manipulate, image

[image]

I need to extract a picture from a red square for further transformation over it.

Comment: let imgTake=ImageTake.... in the manipulate. Then Export[filename.jpg, imgTake].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, assign the ImageTake result to a variable -- that will make it available for further processing, or exporting.

```
pic = Manipulate[Show[img, 
   crop = ImageTake[img, {dR - a - p[[2]], dR + a - p[[2]]}, {p[[1]] - a, p[[1]] + a}]],
  {{p, {dR/2, dC/2}}, Locator}, {a, 20, 100}]
```

[image]

```
crop
```

[image]